# Easily Monitor PC Usage

Tags: windows-xp

Is there a free tool for a standalone Windows XP PC that will monitor either:

- Logon/Logoff Events
- Actual usage (mouse/keyboard time)

I am aware you can set a local policy to log into the eventlog logon/logoff events, but I would like something much simpler such that field staff can log usage of computers that are provided -- such as a library that needs to provide computer use numbers to justify adding extra PC's, or requesting funds to support their operations.

Comment: Most of the software packages that would do this in a graphical way are more designed to spy on your employees... Not a great thing to advertise over here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for something that won't be noticeable.  Aimlessly Googling at lunch I found [Marxio Login Logger](http://www.marxio-tools.net/en/marxio-ll.php) which seems to the trick, but it doesn't have a nice easy installer.

Comment: this should've been an comment.

Comment: Except its the answer to the problem :~)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Wakoopa to track amount of time various apps are open. It can be set to not track actual Web usage, if you want to be privacy-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Logon/logoff events are already monitors. Run *eventvwr* and select the security tab.  If you create a shortcut it's just a couple clicks away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that tsilb is you need to enable logging via a local security policy.  Without a local security policy -- the security log doesn't get used.

[image]

Comment: Now, **this** should have been a comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

siestan, write to the author. I did so with his other product - Marxio Timer. Withing two weeks I saw my requested/suggested setting implemented. Try that with that what you way, maybe you'll be lucky as I was :)